# Is generic creativity and critical thinking impossible to teach or assess?

Tags: education

In the article ['Growth mindset' just another platitude](https://www.cis.org.au/commentary/articles/growth-mindset-just-another-platitude/) published by the Center for independent studies, the author makes the claim that

> Generic creativity or critical-thinking skills are practically
>   impossible to teach or assess.

Is this true? Are there subtleties to consider?

Comment: Is the Center for Independent Studies notable?  (Honest question.  I have no idea whether they are or not.  I just figure it's worth checking, and a bit more info on who they are might help.)

Comment: They are a centre right academic think tank in Australia. They have a following big enough to maintain their existence over a number of years  and occasionally make public comment that finds its way into the media. This claim also fits against the general discussion in needing to teach kids creativity skills for the future economy e.g. STEAM vs STEM skills

Comment: I would say not. Creativity isn't really a skill, just something people have. Also, different people's creativity is different and defines how that person thinks.

Comment: This is two items: 1. Generic creativity is practically impossible to teach or assess and 2. Critical-thinking skills are practically impossible to teach or assess.

Comment: **This can't be answered** because it is unclear what creativity or critically-thinking means in this context, which funnily enough affirms the claim if it weren't for the vague quantifier present which allows for True Scotsman rethoric.